# Why is run_forever required in this sample code?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

In the python asyncio websockets library, the example calls `run_forever()`. Why is this required?

Shouldn't `run_until_complete()` block and run the websockets loop?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
# if you comment out the above line, this doesn't work, i.e., the server
# doesn't actually block waiting for data...
```

If I comment out run_forever(), the program ends immediately.

`start_server` is an awaitable returned by the library. Why isn't `run_until_complete` sufficient to cause it to block/await on `hello()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`websockets.serve`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.server.serve) simply *starts* the server and exits immediately. (It still needs to be awaited because configuring the server can require network communication.) Because of that, you need to actually run the event loop.

Since the server is designed to run indefinitely, you cannot run the event loop in the usual way, by passing a coroutine to `run_until_complete`. As the server has already started, there is no coroutine to run, you just need to let the event loop run and do its job. This is where [`run_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) comes in useful - it tells the event loop to run (executing the tasks previously scheduled, such as those belonging to the server) indefinitely, or until told to stop by a call to [`loop.stop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop).

In Python 3.7 and later one should use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) to run asyncio code, which will create a new event loop, so the above trick won't work. A good way to accomplish the above in modern asyncio code would be to use the [`serve_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server.serve_forever) method (untested):

```
async def my_server():
    ws_server = await websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)
    await ws_server.server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(my_server())
```

Comment: Thank you - I realise now that Protocols need the event loop to be around to do anything useful. It is confusing: Protocols are like ghost Tasks, if you don't keep the loop alive they quietly die, but they don't appear in asyncio.all_tasks(). Wish there was a method asyncio.show_why_i_shouldnt_close_this_loop() returns set of working protocols. The autobahn people also use the pattern


transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
# then...
loop.run_forever()

Comment: @AnthonyAlba The event loop has to be around for **anything** asyncio-related to work, not just protocols and tasks. Protocols are not ghost tasks, they are a **different** high-level abstraction that uses callbacks to do its magic. The callbacks are installed using the basic event loop methods like `add_reader`, `add_writer`, `call_later`, `call_soon`, etc., and it is **these** that need the event loop actually running to keep the wheels turning.